# $n$th Derivative of $_p F_q(a_1,...,a_p; b_1,...,b_q;x^{-m})$, $p \le q$

Tags: hypergeometric-functions, bessel-functions

Maple seems to suggest the following formula for $n>0$, $p \le q$:

\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{d x^n} & {}_p F_q (a_1,\ldots,a_p;b_1,\ldots,b_q;1/x) \\[8pt]
= {} & (-1)^n \hspace{1pt} n!\hspace{2pt} \frac{\prod_j a_j}{\prod_k b_k}\hspace{2pt}  x^{-n-1} {}_{p+1} F_{q+1} (n+1, a_1+1, \ldots, a_p+1; 2, b_1+1, \ldots, b_q+1; 1/x)
\end{align}

It also holds for $n=0$ if $1$ is added to the right hand side. As an example, for $n\ge 1$:

$$ \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\hspace{1pt} \cosh\big(2/\hspace{-1pt}\sqrt{x}\big)  = (-1)^n \hspace{1pt} n!\hspace{2pt} 2\hspace{1pt} x^{-n-1} {}_1 F_2 (n+1\hspace{1pt}; 2,3/2\hspace{1pt}; 1/x)
$$

Does anyone know how this is derived? I haven't seen that formula in classic refs, wikis, or Wolfram. I think it must be based on Cauchy's integral formula, then a change of variable to turn it into a sort of Euler's integral formula for $_{p+1} F_{q+1}$ as a Beta scale mixture of $_p F_q$. I'm not sure how the details of the complex integration would work.

For $n=1$ it's the ordinary derivative formula with the chain rule. So I guess an induction argument would work.

However there is a very interesting more general formula the relates:
$$ \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\hspace{1pt}\normalsize _p F_q (\ldots;\ldots;x^{-m})$$
to a single term involving:
$$ _{p+m} F_{q+m} (\ldots;\ldots;x^{-m})$$
The additional $2 m$ parameters follow a simple pattern. Maybe this would follwo from an iteration for multiple poles in the Cauchy integral due to $m>1$? It doesn't seem to be easily amenable to induction.

There doesn't seem to be a similar formula for integral $m>1$, just the usual increase in terms with $n$. Though it's not clear--Maple returns a single term for the general $n$th derivative with positive integral $m$, but it evaluates to zero (and is incorrect).

For $x^{m/2}$ argument, with $m$ a positive integer, there seems to be an even more interesting single term formula as well, relating:
$$ \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\hspace{1pt}\normalsize _p F_q (\ldots; \ldots; x^{m/2})$$
to a single term involving:
$$ _{2p+m-1}\hspace{-1pt} F\hspace{0.5pt}_{2q+m} (\ldots;\ldots;4^{p-q-1} x^m)$$
where the *F* parameters are halved and incremented by 1 and 1/2, doubling their number, in addition to $2m-1$ patterned fraction parameters. It would be very interesting to know how that is derived.

Edit: the $x^{m/2}$ derivative actually has two terms, not 1. This seems to arise from doing termwise differentiation and then dividing the series into even and odd parts so that the $(mk/2+...)$ coefficients become $(mk+...)$ and $(mk+1/2+...)$ in the new series, which can then be expanded using the Gauss multiplication theorem. Similarly any rational power $m/l$.

Comment: What is your question? Is it about $\ldots 1/x)$ or $\ldots x^{-m})$ or $\ldots x^{m/2})$ or ...? There should be only one question in one post.

Comment: The question is how such formulae are or could be derived. It seems likely the solutions are related. You can take the question as only regarding $x^{-m}$, with the rest as general commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first displayed identity can be verified in a straightforward manner, by differentiating the power series for ${}_{p} F_{q} (a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;1/x)$ (in the powers of $1/x$) term-wise $n$ times in $x$, and then comparing the coefficients of the resulting power series with the coefficients of the power series (in the powers of $1/x$) on the right-hand side of the identity. (Let me know if details on this are needed.)

Expression for the derivatives of any order of ${}_{p} F_{q} (a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;x^c)$ can be obtained similarly, by term-wise differentiation.

Comment: That's certainly a straightforward approach. But to be expressible as a finite parameter generalized hypergeometric function, wouldn't the exponent have to be rational? It seems according to your reasoning there would only be two added parameters plus the $x$ power multiplier. But there are different numbers of added parameters depending on $m$. Does the gamma function turn easily into a product of appropriate terms? Or are there really just 2 additional parameters for all $m$?

Comment: The gamma coefficients need to be of the form $\Gamma(k+a)/\Gamma(a)$. The derivative $x^{ck}$ gives coefficients of the form $\Gamma(ck+a)$. These then can become a product of elementary $\Gamma$ terms by appropriate Gamma multiplicative formulae, but only for rational $c$.

Comment: @japalmer : You seem to be right about (ir)rational $c$.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about the $x^{m/2}$ argument ... The case for $x^{-m}$ follows easily using the Gauss multiplication formula for the $\Gamma(mk)$. I thought there would be a similar formula for $\Gamma(k/m)$, but I just find the double factorial formula for $\Gamma(k/2)$ which isn't a product of gamma functions. Do you know how to expand $\Gamma(k/2)$ into $\prod_j \Gamma(k+a_j)$ ?

Comment: I think there must be a further step as the argument becomes $x^m$ from $x^{m/2}$ in the multiple derivative. There is also the scale change. Maple doesn't return a formula for $x^{1/3}$.

Comment: @japalmer : You may be right about $m/2$.

Comment: So it seems I made a mistake and left a term out, so the $n$th derivate with $x^{m/2}$ argument has 2 terms, not 1. I guess this would follow from dividing the power series into two parts, $2k$, and $2k+1$, $k=0,...,$, so that the $\Gamma(k/2+a)$ become $\Gamma(k+a)$ and $\Gamma(k+1/2+a)$ in the new series. Similarly for $x^{m/3}$ you would have the sum of 3 hypergeometric functions (with a lot of parameters).